# How to conditionally avoid property from serializing in WCF?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization

Is it possible to dynamically avoid property from serializing?
Let's say I have got such a metod in my WCF Service:

```
public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
{
    return new CompositeType();
}
```

Where CompositeType looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    public bool _flag = true;

    [DataMember]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I invoke GetDataUsingDataContract methods, I'm returning CompositeType object, which is then serializing to XML by the WCF technology. Is it possible to avoid Value property from serializing if the _flag = true?

I read about the [XmlIgnore], [IgnoreDataMember] etc., but what I understand this will always ignore property from serializing, I have to ignore only if flag = true. If flag = false I still want to serialize this property.

Comment: Have you looked into [`OnSerializing`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/09/05/wcf-extensibility-serialization-callbacks/) (et al.)?

Comment: Ultimately, `DataContractSerializer` doesn't have good support for conditional serialization. Neither the `SouldSerialize*()` nor `*Specified` patterns are supported :(

Comment: Thanks for you answers, I just read about this and I believe its a good place to initialize properties in the OnSerializing, but how can I make in this property that particular property will be avoided from serializing and response?

Comment: @KennethK. any idea about my response up? Thanks in advance

Comment: @MarcGravell any idea about my response up? Thanks in advance

Comment: Only public properties are serialized.  So you can remove public from any properties you do not want serialized.

Comment: @jdweng how can i dynamically remove public modifier from a propety?

Comment: @jdweng IIRC `DataContractSerializer` is perfectly happy serializing non-public properties; it is only `XmlSerializer` that is fussy about that

Comment: Just remove the word public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your requirement, the following should work.  The property `ValueIfFlagTrue` is for serialization only, name it as you wish.  You haven't said how you want to handle deserializing, so I've made a guess in the implementation: adjust as needed.

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    public bool _flag = true;

    public decimal? Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Value", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    private decimal? ValueIfFlagTrue
    {
        get
        {
            return _flag ? Value : null;
        }
        set
        {
            _flag = value.HasValue ? true : false;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

You can put the `DataMember` attribute on a private property, so there's no need to expose the `ValueIfFlagTrue` property publicly.

Comment: Joe one question, why this ValueIfFlag did you make private? Any particular reason?

Comment: @CSharpBeginner - the reason is encapsulation / information hiding: this property is an implementation detail that is only used for serialization, and therefore it's best to hide it from users of the class.  Incidentally you probably shouldn't have a public field "_flag", but instead have a suitable property, but I assume that `CompositeType` is only an example to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks, after all your answer helped me a lot!!:)

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to apply. You should implement your custom serialization rules. In your case, you could use `EmitDefaultValue` and declare the decimal as `nullable`.

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    public bool _flag = true;

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

You should set the `Value` as null if the `_flag` is  false. If the `Value` is null, it will not be serialized. It would be easier way for you.

Comment: I believe this doesn't solve cases when Value will be null, and I want to serialize it and return in response?

Comment: Well, you should implement custom serialization rules. Why don't you return the Flag property too. Client would handle it. In my opinion, implementing custom serializer would be over engineering.

Comment: I have to integerate my service with another company. They got one demand: in response they want only properties that are needed. Due to that 2 methods in my service returns pretty similar model I wanted to use 1 class in both methods and just control serializing couple of fields by a flag instead of creating 2 pretty same classes.. Looks like it will be hard to avoid that...

Comment: I see. in your code snippet the decimal value is not nullable already. Why don't you use my solution ?

Comment: Because these propeties cannot be visible in response. If i set to null I will still have in response <Value></Value>. Thats the problem, I have to clear it from serializing and response as the DataMember attrubute didnt exist

Comment: If you use "EmitDefaultValue", it won't be serialized as you expected if the property is null.

Comment: What about the case when the Value will be null and I want it to be serialized?

Comment: You shared the property "decimal Value" as non-nullable already. So, I assume that you are not planning to send null value. Am I right ?

Comment: This was my mistake :/, unfortunalety it can be null, sorry, already edited the question.