# Is there a way to conditionally expose properties at runtime to a WCF client?

Tags: c#, wcf, filter, properties

Consider a WCF service that can do something like this on the client side:

```
IMyClass MyClass = getSomeClass("MyClass");
```

Where IMyClass is:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    string Property1 { get; set; }

    bool Property2 { get; set; }

    int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, all these properties get initialised out of some JSON file at runtime. The JSON contains init values for all the parameters we want to expose to the client.

In some cases though, we may have init values for Property1 only. It means that the client should not be able to see Property2 or Property3. I understand that this specific example does not work since the interface is explicitely telling the client about Properties 2 and 3.

But, I was wondering if there was a way to filter out these properties (or even methods) of a class at runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally avoid property from serializing in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267916/how-to-conditionally-avoid-property-from-serializing-in-wcf)

Comment: Consider making an interface that has only the one property, then a second interface that inherits from it and adds the other two properties. Then use the one with only property when you only want to expose that

Comment: @Selim Yıldız, not quite. In your example, the property name is still exposed. It just conditionaly gets serialised.

Comment: @Chronicle, that does not work. I don't want the client to know about these properties when not defined/initialised. Relying on interfaces means the client always knows about everything.

Comment: If it is not about serializing, maybe you should think about use inheritance. I mean create objects for each case which are implemented base Interface. On client side cast interface to proper object.